# How to use 2 GIT Repos in a Project? (git submodules, subtree)

Tags: git

We are working on a project which has multiple folders some of them are as follows :-

**Core

Contrib

Vendor**

*Languages

Skins

Config*

We have deployed the project on 10 different servers for 10 different client, the contents of the first 3 folders are same (common) for all the clients, but the contents of last 3 folders vary for each client, i was wondering how we would maintain this in git.

For the time being we have 1 repository which contains the code for the first 3 folders (common for all clients) and rest of the remaining 3 folders have been avoided by using gitignore.

I wanted to know if we can make 10 config branches or repos for each client which would contain the data for the last 3 folders (which vary for each client), i have gone through sub-modules and some other solutions, but still if someone could guide me with a good architecture for this.

Answer (score 1):

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

## ***`git submodule`***

Break your big project to sub projects as you did described it.
Set each piece in its **own repo**;

Now add each sub project to you main project using :

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Once the projected is added tot your repo you have to init and update it.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

As of **Git 1.8.2** new option `--remote` was added

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will ***`fetch`*** the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, ***`merge them in`***, and ***`check out`*** the latest revision of the submodule.

As [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) describe it:

> ***`--remote`***
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running git pull in each submodule.

---

> ***However, how would I push a commit in the scenario of bug fix in C which affects the code shared with the parent layers?***

Again: using submodule will place your code inside your main project as part of its content. The difference between having it locally inside the folder or having it as part of a submodule is that in submodule the content is managed (commited) to a different standalone repository.

---

This is an illustration of submodule - project inside another project in which each project is a standalone project.

[image]

---

## ***`git subtree`***

***Git subtree allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one***

Very similar to `submodule` but the main difference is where your code is managed. In submodules the content is placed inside a separate repo and is managed there which allow you to clone it to many other repos as well.

***`subtree`*** is managing the content as part of the root project and not in a separate project.

Instead of writing down how to set it up and to understand how to use it you can simply read this excellent post which will explain it all.

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide your project into multiple repository, I would like recommend you to use [repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html), which google developed to manage Android project, to manage multiple git repositories.  It is very convenient to write a manifest file for each client to maintain all your project.

Comment: How about using 2 remotes and pushing and pulling the changes from respective remotes ?

Comment: @Sameer You can specify different remote for each repository in manifest file.  By repo, You can operate each repository separately or as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Don't deploy your entire git repo to each client. Instead, store the config for each client in a directory, and have a simple deployment process that deploys only the appropriate config directory to each client. That is, in your repo you would have:

- Core
- Contrib
- Vendor
- Configs

  - Client1

    - Languages
    - Skins
    - Config
  - Client2

    - Languages
    - Skins
    - Config
  - ...

And when it comes time to deploy to client1's server, you don't send the entire git repo with its history, but just the current tree (with only Client1's config):

- Core
- Contrib
- Vendor
- Languages
- Skins
- Config

Answer (score -1):

Keeping more than one repository for one project is not a good way to go. If you want different config for different purposes, as you said you should go with different branches.

Then you will have

```
master -> 
   client_1
   client_2
   client_3
   ...
```

But keeping all together is difficult though.

Another way is keeping a config file for each client and use that file to load different folders.

like:

```
CLIENT_1: {
   LANG: 'languages_1',
   SKINS: 'skins_1'
},
CLIENT_2: {
   ...
   ...
}
```

And use the config to load appropriate folder according to the environment.