# How to develop for different environments

Tags: java, git, maven, jira

I am developing a JIRA plugin that should work under JIRA 6 and 7. Unfortunately there are major API changes between those versions and I have to build the project with different dependencies for each JIRA version.

The core of my plugin should not be changed between the versions, thus I thought about creating an abstraction layer for the JIRA API tht provides only methods that I need.

The main problem is, that I absolutely don't know how to structure the project. I considered to create a branch in git for each JIRA version, but then I would have to make the same changes on the core in each branch. I suspect that I will get forget this at some point.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the plugins based on build tool `maven` ?

Comment: make a separate module **core**, **jira6**, **jira7** and may be more ...and you can defined different dependencies for **jira6** and **jire7**. Branch does not sounds right...BTW: You might need to create **api** module which contains the translation between the different versions...

Answer (score 0):

[image] Three different modules

Here is one of the proposed structure, [image: dependencies]

By implementing the `maven` version changes, there can be a module level version changes.

And again for the code base changes, there has to be git branch change where the backporting should happen.

Lets say version 6 is in a branch and the changes you want in the version 7, 
As it is one of the common change, the file has to be core module and as well there should be a healthy merge between these branches.

Answer (score 0):

Use submodules.

Your structure should like like this:

```
+ ROOT Project 1
| - Common (shared between your projects = submodule)
| - Project specific code


+ ROOT Project 2
| - Common (shared between your projects = submodule)
| - Project specific code
```

Read this full answer about it, how to use it and what can you gain from it.

[How to use 2 GIT Repos in a Project? (git submodules, subtree)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950201/how-to-use-2-git-repos-in-a-project/35982071#35982071)

[image]